# How do i solve $(2+i)z^2-(5-i)z+2-2i=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help solving $$(2+i)z^2-(5-i)z+2-2i=0$$ I have no idea how to start solving this equation so help would be nice.

Comment: Do you know how to apply the formula for quadratic equations? Begin with calculation of the discriminant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the quadratic equation using the formula we obtain:

$$Δ=(i-5)^2-4\cdot (i+2)\cdot (2-2i)=...=-2i$$

So, now we need to find out $\sqrt{-2i}$. We equate this to a complex number $z=a+b\cdot i$. So, we have: $$(a+b\cdot i)^2=-2i\Leftrightarrow ...\Leftrightarrow (a^2-b^2)+2abi=0-2i\Leftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a^2=b^2 \\ 
ab=-1
\end{array}
\right.
\Rightarrow a^2\cdot b^2=1\Leftrightarrow a^4=1\Leftrightarrow a=\pm 1, b=\mp 1\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{-2i}=1-i$$

Let's note here that because the above in the final quadratic solution formula is with $\pm$, it doesn't matter whether we take $1-i$ or $-1+i$.

Plug into the final formula:

$$z_{1,2}=\frac{5-i\pm (1-i)}{2\cdot (i+2)}=...=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{3-i}{i+2} \\[2ex]
\frac{2}{i+2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Again we try express those two as final, complex numbers (each time let $z=a+b\cdot i$):

$$1) (3-i)=(a+b\cdot i)\cdot (i+2)\Leftrightarrow ...\Leftrightarrow (2a-b)+i\cdot (2b+a)=3-i
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2a-b=3 \\ 
2b+a=-1
\end{array}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow ...\Leftrightarrow a=1, b=-1$$

$$2) 2=(a+b\cdot i)\cdot (i+2)\Leftrightarrow ...\Leftrightarrow (2a-b)+i\cdot (2b+a)=2
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2a-b=2 \\ 
2b+a=0
\end{array}
\right.
\Leftrightarrow ...\Leftrightarrow a=\frac{4}{5}, b=-\frac{2}{5}$$

So, indeed, we have two solutions to this equation:

$$z_1=1-i$$
$$z_2=\frac{4}{5}-\frac{2}{5}i$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Solve it as quadratic equation:
$$(2+i)z^2-(5-i)z+2-2i=0\\ z=\frac { { \left( 5-i \right) \pm \sqrt { { \left( 5-i \right)  }^{ 2 }-4\left( 2+i \right) \left( 2-2i \right)  }  } }{ 2\left( 2+i \right)  } $$

Comment: it can be simplified to $$1-I$$ and $$\frac{4}{5}-\frac{2}{5}I$$

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is $\Delta=-2\mathrm i$, and the problem is to compute its square roots.

Here it is easy: every one who studied complex numbers noticed that $(1\pm\mathrm i)^2=\pm2\mkern1mu\mathrm i$.

However, I'll explain the *general method* to compute the square roots of $a+\mathrm i\mkern1mu b$, i.e. solve:
$$(x+\mathrm i\mkern1mu y)^2=a+\mathrm i\mkern1mub\iff\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=a\\2xy=b\end{cases}$$
Also, note the square of the module of $x+\mathrm i\mkern1mu y$ is equal to the module of $a+\mathrm i\mkern1mu b$, i.e.
$$(x^2+y^2)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
Let's denote $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. We have to first solve the linear system:
$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=a\\x^2+y^2=r\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}x^2=\frac12(r+a)\\[1ex]y^2=\frac12(r-a)\end{cases}$$
Thus it seems there is $4$ solutions ($2$ for $x$, $2$ for $y$). However, there is a third relation: $\;2xy=b$, so $x$ and $y$ must have the same sign if $b>0$, opposite signs if $b<0$, hence there are only two solutions if $b\ne 0$.

In the case $b=0$, $r=\lvert a\rvert$, so one of $x,y$ is $0$, and there are only two square roots also in this case.